# Is it legal/safe to cast away `const` for a heap-allocated object?

Tags: c, casting, constants, undefined-behavior, const-correctness

My use case is as follows.

I develop a library in which some loaded plugins can create objects (allocated using `malloc()` by the library), and some other plugins can read properties of those objects but not modify them.

For me this is a case of having a non-`const` API for the creating/writer side and a `const` API for the reader side, for example:

```
// writer API
struct obj *obj_create(void);
void obj_set_some_property(struct obj *obj, int property);

// reader API
int obj_get_some_property(const struct obj *obj);
```

The library casts a `struct obj *` (created by the writer side) to a `const struct obj *` (available to the reader side).

My problem is that those objects also have reference counts, and the reader side can call your typical reference count incrementation/decrementation functions. Those functions need to modify the object.

My question is: in this specific context, is it safe for the reference count incrementation/decrementation functions to accept a `const struct obj *` and cast away the `const` internally? Note that the reference count decrementation function could also destroy (free) the object if the count reaches zero.

I know that §6.7.3¶5 says:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, **the behavior is undefined**.

I just can't figure out what *defined with a const-qualified type* means. Does this apply if my object is heap-allocated? I totally understand why it would be UB to do so with a literal string pointer (`.rodata`), for example. But what if the object is created to be non-`const` in the beginning?

[`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) is a well known example of casting `const` away: it accepts `const char *` and returns `char *`, which points within the `const char *` parameter. How is this legal considering §6.7.3¶5?

Comment: It all depends on how the original pointer was allocated. The `const` qualifier primarily allows the compiler to help you by warning if there is an attempted modification, as well as allowing the compiler to further optimize based on your promise that the object won't be modified. As you have found, you can break that promise by casting away the `const` qualifier, but .. then you are on your own and you must guarantee the memory is mutable and in the case of `free`, previously allocated with `malloc, calloc or realloc`. The need to cast away generally shows a defect in code design.

Comment: A cast does not modify an object. Casting away const is never UB.  It might be UB if you go on to use the result of the cast in order to modify a const object.

Comment: Language lawyer stuff: What matters is the effective type of the object. The data pointed at by malloc has no type until you do a lvalue access of the data - in which case the "effective type" becomes the one you used for access. And I think it is impossible to make a lvalue access with a const-qualified type(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, **defined** refers to the program statement defining the variable, such as `const struct obj x = {};`.  This is as opposed to a statement merely declaring it, such as `const struct obj* x;`.

In C, memory returned by `malloc` is uninitialized storage that can be safely written to.  In fact, your library must have done this at least once before passing the structure to the client!

In theory, you might have a problem if the client somehow declared a `const obj x = OBJ_INITIALIZER;` and then passed it to your library.  Your compiler might have stuck that variable definition into a read-only page of memory, or might optimize too aggressively on the assumption that it can never be modified.  So you would need to specify that any library function that casts away `const` internally works *only* on objects from its own factories.

One way to ensure that untrusted client code can’t violate this assumption is to pass in handles rather than object pointers, but your library might not need to bother.

You might also conceivably run into problems if the client code uses the fields you modify, and if the compiler assumes that a function that takes a `const struct obj*` parameter cannot modify it through that parameter.  You might work around that by returning a reference that aliases the object, which the compiler will not assume is the same unmodified object (or, I guess, by abusing `volatile`).

In C++, you would have the option of declaring the fields that need to be modified `mutable`.

Comment: My library only uses opaque handles indeed (see the `obj_create()` example), so I don't think I have the initializer issue. _and if the compiler assumes that a function that takes a `const struct obj *` parameter cannot modify it through that parameter_: wouldn't this make the compiler broken then, because it's only a `const` (parameter) declaration at this point? Is this a drawback of using an initializer instead of handles?

Comment: @eepp If you're only passing in opaque handles, neither problem arises. (But you can probably avoid passing pointers to structures that you would need to cast in this way.)

Answer (score 3):

Objects allocated by `malloc` do not have any type, let alone a const-qualified one. It is fine to modify them regardless of whether you pointed to the object with a pointer-to-const at some stage.

"defined with a const-qualified type" requires that the object had a definition (`malloc` is a function call, not a definition).